# logon on remote computer powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, wmi

i found that nice command

```
(gwmi win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName remote-pc).Win32Shutdown(4)
```

it logout user from remote-pc 
but i wonder is there any command to login to remote-pc?
i don't thinking about `Enter-PSSesion`, i'm rather thinking about some remote-pc where is windows with prompt to login "press ctrl+alt+del to login" and instead to do it, i executed command on other PC to unlock and login to this remote-pc

Does WMI or other stuff in powershell can do it?